# SSAS Data Source View Does Not Show newly added column

Tags: ssis, ssas

I am newbie on SSAS. I added a new column to a destination table in SQL Server. I also mapped the new column in an ssis package, but data source view in Cube does not show the column. I've already checked the connection and host. All are correct but when I refresh the dsv the column does not appear. If I add the column on dsv , I'll add the column as measure. By the way the project has already deployed.

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: add more details plz. or add screenshot

Comment: I solve the problem. Thanks for responses.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit the DSV and explicitly add the column.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue on SSAS when trying to add new column from a view ( that view came from different view(in different db)). It did not pop up when we refreshed DATA SOURCE VIEWS (DSV).
if you are in the DSV already, double click the table/view where that field is locatad. It will open a table structure and you can simply add it picking up desired field.